# passing value from gridview to textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wonder how I can pass value from gridview to textbox in vb.net?

I tried something like

```
  textbox1.text=gridview1.rows(1).cells(1).value
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific than doesn't work?

Comment: it shows error that 'value' is not a member of system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell

Comment: Please always add any clarifications to your question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

OK, after I tried textbox1.text=gridview1.rows(1).cells(1).text, it works now.
Thanks!