# deleting and updating records both on datagridview and mysql database (vb2010)

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am a newbie to vb 2010. 
I am trying to delete and as well update records that I have selected 
On the datagrid and the deleted or updated data also is deleted or updated in the mysql database.
 Please someone help

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't know if you are using VB or C#.. but here are some tips to do that..

You have to create textboxes or whatever you need.. then on Datagrid Cell `OnClick` event, you have to pass each values from datagrid to textboxes and then you can now edit the values, after editing.. when you are clicking the save button.. you have to rebind the datagrid, meaning to say.. you have to call again the `DataGridView1.DataBind` at the end of the saving logic.

To delete the data, same logic goes.. after clicking the datagrid, pass the id of that data into textbox , and then you can now delete the data using where clause.. the SQL syntax is something like this.. `DELETE FROM TableNameHere WHERE ID = Textbox1.Text`

[passing value from gridview to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797575/passing-value-from-gridview-to-textbox)

Regards.